# Short circuit delta

Tags: circuit-analysis, fault

Assuming I have the following system:

[image]

and a single-phase fault is on the 2.4 kV side. How do I calculate the voltage between the neutral resistor and ground? How do I calculate the zero sequence current within the delta? I tried connecting the sequences diagrams in series, but \$I_0=0\$ (the line zero sequence is zero as expected).

[image]

Comment: Your 2.4 kV bus fed from the Delta is a ungrounded.  The ground fault just corner grounds the delta.  I presume the Rg you mention is in the neutral of the wye winding (which you show on the hv side). With no zero sequence current, there’s no voltage drop across that resistor so the neutral (star point)  is at ground potential.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!